# Has appending lights and cameras been deprecated?

Tags: camera, light, append

I find in recent versions (2.69a, 2.7, 2.71) of Blender that I cannot append lights or cameras from one ~.Blend file to another. The documentation suggests that this used to be possible in versions prior to 2.5, but there is no documentation related to appending or liking for newer versions. Is it no longer possible to append lights and cameras from one file to another?

Comment: What folder are you appending this from?

Comment: [Sheepish grin]Apparently the wrong one. I was trying to append from the "lamp" folder, instead of appending the lamp object from the object folder. Thanks for the help. [/Sheepish grin]

Comment: It's a good question. Let me add an answer for future ref since it might be asked in the future, had the same problem years ago as well ;).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just like how you cannot append an actual object from *Mesh*, you can't append scene objects from *Lamp* or *Camera* either. To append an ***object*** from another scene, you need to go into the ***Objects*** folder.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you.